# Googleフォームのアップロード機能でアップした回答者のファイルをフォーム送信後に削除したい

Tags: google-apps-script

現在Googleフォームでアップロード機能を使ったフォームの運用を考えています。

まずGoogleフォームの仕様ですが
送信前に回答者がファイルのアップロードを行った時点で
回答者がオーナーのファイルが回答者のドライブ(直下)に保存されます。

その後フォームを送信すると
フォーム作成者側のドライブのファイル保存場所に
フォーム作成者側がオーナーのアップロードファイルが保存されます。

そこでですが、このままですと
回答者が意識してフォーム送信後に
自分のドライブ直下にアップされたファイルを消していかないと
ドライブ直下にアップロードファイルが溜まり続ける状態となってしまうため
なんとかGASやその他の手段(あれば)を用いて
フォーム送信後に回答者のアップロードファイルを削除したいと考えております。

現状、インターネットや書籍を参考に、フォームのGASでは以下のように
回答内容を取得してメールを送信するプログラムを書いております。

```
function noticeFileUpload(e) {
    var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

    for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) { 
        var itemResponse = itemResponses[i]; 
        var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(); 
        var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();

        Logger.log(question);
        Logger.log(answer);

        if(question == "提出書類"){
            var fileId = answer;
            var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

            var address = 'メールアドレス'; 
            var title = '【Google Form送信テスト】ファイルがアップロードされました'; 
            var content = 'ファイルがアップロードされました。\n\n'
            + 'ファイル名：' + file.getName()
            + '\n\n'
            + '※このメールはGoogleフォームからの自動送信メールです。'; 

            GmailApp.sendEmail(address, title, content);
        }
    }
}
```

このように、回答内容を取得するコードはわかるのですが
回答者が自分のドライブにアップしたファイルを取得する具体的なコードがわかりません。

回答内容で保存されたファイルの名前から、自動付加された後ろのアカウント名を削除し
同じ名前のファイルをドライブ直下から検索→削除といった処理をしなければならないのでしょうか。
（その場合、既に同じ名前のファイルがあった場合などの対応も気がかりです）

すいませんがご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

結論から言えば、可能です。

以下のドキュメントを読めば、やり方の一助になります。

[Forms Service  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) 
 [Drive Service  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/)

Google Apps Script自体の書き方については、ご自身で勉強していただくしかないのが実情でありますが、ES5をベースとして、インターネット上や書籍にも多数の情報があり、比較的入門者にも学びやすい言語であるため、頑張ってください。
[Overview of Google Apps Script  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
[【保存版】初心者向け実務で使えるGoogle Apps Script完全マニュアル](https://tonari-it.com/google-apps-script-manual/)

#### 追記 2019-03-05_15-29-37

Google Form側のWebクライアントの機能で、回答結果をスプレッドシートに書き込むことが出来ます（新しい回答も自動的に追記・編集されていきます）。

そして、このスプレッドシートには回答者がアップロードしたファイルのGoogle Drive側のURLも回答の項目として記載されているため、このURLからファイルのIDを取得、 `DriveApp.getFileById` を利用して[File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)を取得し、後は `File.getParents` で親[Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)を取得することで`Folder.removeFile`を実行して実際にファイルを削除することが出来ます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

一応昔はプログラマをやっており、プログラム自体やGASのことがさっぱりわからないということではないのですが、本件に関してはアップロードしたファイルの取得の仕方などの具体的ところをお聞きしたいと思い投稿させていただきました。

投稿内容が曖昧でしたので、修正いたします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: かしこまりました。ゼロからのスタートだと考えてふんわりした回答にしてしまったのですが、詳細について記述します。

Comment: 迅速な再回答、誠に感謝いたします。

回答結果をスプレッドシートに書き込むところは運用上利用したいところであり、確認していたところですが、「回答者がアップロードしたファイルのGoogle Drive側のURLも回答の項目として記載されている」というのは初めて知りました。

自分が確認した限りでは、保存した側のドライブ(フォーム作成者側のドライブのファイル保存場所に保存された、フォーム作成者側がオーナーのアップロードファイル)のURLしかなかった気がしますが、ちょっと確認してみます。

追って報告させていただきます。
未解決であった場合は改めてご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: PicoSushi様　多忙な状況になってしまい、確認が遅くなりました。PicoSushi様がおっしゃられていた「回答者がアップロードしたファイルのGoogle Drive側のURLも回答の項目として記載されている」の件ですが、やはり回答用のスプレッドシートにはフォーム作成者側のドライブの保存場所に保存されたフォーム作成者側がオーナーのアップロードファイルのURLしか出てきておらず、「このURLからファイルのIDを取得、 DriveApp.getFileById を利用してFileを取得し、後は File.getParents で親Folderを取得することでFolder.removeFileを実行して実際にファイルを削除することが出来ます。」の処理を実現することができません。DriveApp.getFileById、File.getParentsで取得できるのはフォーム作成者側のドライブの保存場所になってしまいます。「回答者がアップロードしたファイルのGoogle Drive側のURLも回答の項目として記載されている」がどれを指すのか、ご教授願えますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらですが、その後も調べましたがフォーム回答者側のドライブのファイルにアクセスする術は見つかりませんでした。
おそらくできないということで、質問は閉じさせていただければと存じます。